# Recommended way to clean Git history during/before a release, add new commits and bring back changes to dev

Tags: python, git, bitbucket

We are a small development group that follows gitflow(https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) with "fast-forward only" merge strategy. Prior to merging, all commits are squashed to the associated Jira issue manually. As a result we have a clean and continuous history of features, user stories, bugfixes and hotfixes that can be easily tracked through Jira.

As a team we have reached some doubts regarding opening new releases while continuing working in development. One of our release tasks is to clean the possible fixups or rephrase commits, while adding new commits fixing issues our clients are detecting in the release. Once the release is ready, we want to move forward to master while bringing back the changes of the release to development, including all squashed commits, rephrases and bugfixes. Our last release didn't go as expected and we had to manually add each each commit to dev through cherry-picking and squashing to be in sync with master, as it went way far ahead than master and tens of merge conflicts where appearing.

So, what is the best approach to maintain a clean history even in development when working in the release branch alongside development? Should we clean dev. prior to opening the release? How can we add new bugfixes without breaking our history in dev?

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't actually understand what went wrong with your Git workflow.  Can you add a diagram and/or more information about what went wrong?

Comment: Basically, we created the release branch with whatever was in development at the time (pretty cleaned up already). Then we proceeded to further improve the history of the release, squashing and rewriting some commits. Finally, when we tried to merge back the changes to dev alongside 2 new bugfixes, we had a huge stack of merge conflicts for most of the squashed or rewritten commits.